# Convert Python Script to Google Sheets Script

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

The following code block is a python script with added Google Sheets script method title and arguments. I would like to use this code in a Google Sheets custom script.

```
function D20PROBS(INPUT1, INPUT2) {
    count=0
    for i in range(1,21):
        for j in range(1,21):
            if i+INPUT1 > j+INPUT2:
                count+=1
    print(count)
}
```

Comment: will this help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM and that's not how you create a function in python

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient way to do what I need. It's adding a lot of extra steps. I feel like it'd be easier to just change the code into something that Google Sheets Scripts understand

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Does "Google Sheets Scripts" mean "Google Apps Script"? Do you want to use the output (``count``) calculated by your python script as a custom function for Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script? If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: The code you've posted is not python.

Comment: I want it to be a custom function in Google Sheets. You can add custom functions by using their code that's based on Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

#### Modification points :

- `for i in range(1,21):` can be converted to `for (var i=1; i<21; i++) {}`
- `f i+INPUT1 > j+INPUT2:` can be converted to `if (i+INPUT1 > j+INPUT2) {}`
- `print(count)` was converted to `return count` for importing the result to the cell.

#### Modified script :

```
function D20PROBS(INPUT1, INPUT2) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i=1; i<21; i++) {
    for (var j=1; j<21; j++) {
      if (i+INPUT1 > j+INPUT2) {
        count+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

#### Note :

- You can use this function on Spreadsheet as a custom function. When you use this, please copy and paste this script to the script editor which is opened on Spreadsheet, and put `=D20PROBS(number, number)` to a cell.
- `INPUT1` and `INPUT2` are necessary to be numbers.

Comment: That's beautiful! Thank you very much, Tanaike! :) It worked like a charm.

Comment: @Mikitz06 I'm glad this was useful for you. Thank you, too.